# Display Paragraph with same format(With line Break)

Tags: c#, html

I store two paragraphs in sql server in same field. My Problem is while retrieving data from database and display in the report it display both paragraphs as single Paragraph. But while using TextArea it displays good. but Is there any options to display Paragraphs as i stored in HTML

Comment: Maybe report doesn't support html markup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be great if you provide what tag you have been using or just a code sample of your current project.

But this sounds like the paragraph is being displayed inline, possibly from `span` , `i` or no tags at all.

If you have no wrappers, wrap it inside `<div> Quack! </div>` or `<p> Quack!</p>`. 
If you have existing wrappers and would like to keep them, set their css styling into `display: block`.

I guess this is the best I could answer without a slight clue of what the sample is.

Or if you are injecting results from the server, this would mean a different case and you will need to loop through the results and wrap each of them.